# How can I calculate power consumption of the amplifier from its datasheet?

Tags: amplifier, rf, power-consumption

In datasheet of the transistor, CGHV40100, I could not find the power consumption of its. How can I calculate the power consumption? 
[Datasheet of the CGHV40100](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/90/ghv40100-876399.pdf)

Comment: That entirely depends on how you drive it

Comment: Can you give me more detail about it, @PlasmaHH ? I apply 50 V and 0.6 A.

Comment: You are the one having to provide details. How you bias it, what signal you drive into, a schematic would be really useful here. We have no idea what you are doing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** an amplifier, it's GaN HEM**T** where the **T** stands for **T**ransistor. With such a transistor you can build an amplifier.

You choose a very niche type of transistor, it is designed for high power (more than 100 W) RF applications up to 2.5 GHz. I wonder why you have chosen this type of transistor as it requires **a lot of experience** to work with them.

By that I mean that this transistor must be used in a certain way, things to consider are:

- what is the frequency (band) of interest to you
- how much signal gain do you design the amplifier for
- what biasing voltages and currents are then needed
- what will be the matching components at input and output
- signal distortion, a trade-off against efficiency must be made
- what cooling solution will you use

To get an indication, from the datasheet, in **their** 1 GHz measurement / testcase the saturated power is 100 W at an efficiency of 56 %. That means that about 178 Watt is consumed in total. And output is 56% * 178 W = 100 W. So about 78 W is dissipated as heat. That's a lot, good cooling is needed at this power level.

This is just one example case, for your particular case the numbers will be different.